# How can I dynamically control the width of a react-bootstrap-table-next table column?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

Below is what my table looks like in code. How can i control each column and make them have different widths?

````
  { id: 1, name: "Item 1", price: 100 },
  { id: 2, name: "Item 2", price: 102 }
];

const ProductList = props => {
  const columns = [
    {
      dataField: "id",
      text: "Product ID"
    },
    {
      dataField: "name",
      text: "Product Name"
    },
    {
      dataField: "price",
      text: "Product Price"
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
      <h1 className="h2">Products</h1>
      <BootstrapTable keyField="id" data={products} columns={columns} />
    </div>
  );
};```
````

Comment: Did you try to give `width` to `column`. `{dataField: "id", text: "Product ID", style:{'width' : '90px'}}`

Comment: ok, let approve the my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use style prop

```
{
  dataField: "name",

  style: { 
    width: '90px' 
  }
  text: "Product Name"

}
```

Answer (score -1):

While surfing and searching for the solution, i stumbled upon their well documented [doc page](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Work%20on%20Columns&selectedStory=Customize%20Column%20Class&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel). Initially, it's the name **react-bootstrap-table-next** that was confusing me: it is well known as react-bootstrap-table2.

So, to control the width of a react-bootstrap-table-next table column, you should add *classes* props to style it externally or *style* to use inline style. Both props have the capability to take a callback function to better manipulate it.

The code will now look like below:

Here manipulating the width of the first column:

```
const ProductList = props => {
  const columns = [
    {
      dataField: "id",
      text: "Product ID",
style: {
    width: '12em',
  }
    },
    {
      dataField: "name",
      text: "Product Name"
    },
    {
      dataField: "price",
      text: "Product Price"
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
      <h1 className="h2">Products</h1>
      <BootstrapTable keyField="id" data={products} columns={columns} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The [storybook](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Work%20on%20Columns&selectedStory=Customize%20Column%20Class&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel) is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score -1):

Just give the `width` to `columns`

```
const columns = [
    {
      dataField: "id",
      text: "Product ID",
      style:{'width' : '90px'}
    },
    {
      dataField: "name",
      text: "Product Name",
      style:{'width' : '90px'}
    },
    {
      dataField: "price",
      text: "Product Price",
      style:{'width' : '90px'}
    }
  ];
```